# Can the source code of libc6-dbg be downloaded? Where can it be downloaded from?

Tags: valgrind, libc

After porting valgrind to an ARM board, it failed to run with an error indicating that libc6-dbg was required.
So I wanted to download the source code of libc6-dbg for cross-compilation and then port it to the ARM board. However, I couldn’t find the source code of libc6-dbg after searching for a long time.
Could you please tell me where I can download the source code of libc6-dbg?
The error:

```
==22742== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22742== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22742== Using Valgrind-3.22.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22742== Command: /app/meta8k/meta8k_mat_server
==22742==

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
valgrind:
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:
valgrind:  Note that if you are debugging a 32 bit process on a
valgrind:  64 bit system, you will need a corresponding 32 bit debuginfo
valgrind:  package (e.g. libc6-dbg:i386).
valgrind:
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

To obtain the source code of libc6-dbg for cross-compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it from [enter link description here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git)

The glibc source code is also available on Git. You can clone the repository using the following command: git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git

Comment: Thank you for your response; the address you provided is for GCC 6. According to my research, libc6-dbg is the debug version of the GNU C Library, while GCC 6 is a compiler. Are they the same thing?